# Wait for for loop to be executed in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a for loop that creates products in the database and also want that productsarray to be pushed in another collection ,so I want it to store in a temporary array,but before executing the complete for loop the javascript control goes and executes the rest of the code due to which the temporary array is empty.
I want something so that the javascript control goes to next statement only after the for loop is executed completely.

```js
for(let i=0;i<productsname.length;i++){
        name=productsname[i]
        cost=productcost[i]
        Product.create({name:name,cost:cost},function(err,product){
            productArray.push(product);
        })
    }
var newOrder={id:count++,dateofdispatch:req.body.date,transport:req.body.transport,amount:req.body.totalcost,product:productArray}
```

Comment: You may accept one of the answers below. If those not working for you, you may give them feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this you can do something like this:

```js
let numCreated = 0;
for(let i=0;i<productsname.length;i++){
        name=productsname[i]
        cost=productcost[i]
        Product.create({name:name,cost:cost},function(err,product){
            productArray.push(product);
            numCreated++;
            if(numCreated === productsname.length){
              onLoopCompleted(productArray);
            }
        })
    }

function onLoopComplete(productArray){
  var newOrder =  { id: count++, dateofdispatch: req.body.date, transport: req.body.transport, amount: req.body.totalcost, product: productArray }
  // Do what needs to be done here
}
```

If the library you are using is a promise compliant, then you can look at `Promise.all`

Comment: Thanks,Was a simple solution to implement

Answer (score 1):

What you can do:

First you can create a promise for Product.create

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { ... });
```

then you can create an array with your promises and start all by:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(res => {  })
```

See: [MDN Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [MDN Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Try this:

```
const promises = [];
for (let i=0; i<productsname.length; i++){
    const name = productsname[i];
    const cost = productcost[i];
    promises.push(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Product.create({name,cost},(err,product) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(product);
                    }
                }):
        })
    );
}

Promise.all(promises).then(res => {  
    console.info(res);
    // TODO what you want
});
```

PS:  {name:name,cost:cost}  short form: {name,cost}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an asynchronous design pattern. `Promise.all` seems to fit exactly your requirement but I don't know if the library you are using for mongodb is Promise  compliant.

If your library is not Promise compliant you can implement them by yourself.

```
let promiseArray;

for(let i=0;i<productsname.length;i++){
    name=productsname[i]
    cost=productcost[i]
    promiseArray.push(new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        Product.create({name:name,cost:cost},function(err,product) {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(product);
        })
    }));
}

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(yourResultArray => {
    // rest of your program goes here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a temporary Array just do it

```
const procductArray = [];
```

your FOR loop

```
for(let i=0;i<productsname.length;i++){
        const newProduct = {
        name=productsname[i]
        cost=productcost[i]
        }
      Product.create({name:newProduct.name,cost:newProduct.cost},function(err,product){
            productArray.push(newProduct);
        })
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not the question. The problem is, that productArray.push is executed in a callback (later) --> Array is not filled after the for loop (where the array should be used)

Comment: what is productArray? It will contain all products okay?

Comment: I'm afraid that you misunderstood the question. It's a timing problem. Async  execution problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should synchronize your code either with Promise or async/await.

Check code below for await example :

```js
(async function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < productsname.length; i++) {
    name = productsname[i];
    cost = productcost[i];
    await Product.create({ name: name, cost: cost }, function (err, product) {
      productArray.push(product);
    });
  }
  var newOrder = await {
    id: count++,
    dateofdispatch: req.body.date,
    transport: req.body.transport,
    amount: req.body.totalcost,
    product: productArray,
  };
  // do another thing and dont forget to use await

})();
```

await expression can only be used in async function. Above code create an async function and immediately calls it. It is called an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression). You may also create an async function and use somewhere else :

```js
async function createProductArray () {
  for (let i = 0; i < productsname.length; i++) {
    name = productsname[i];
    cost = productcost[i];
    await Product.create({ name: name, cost: cost }, function (err, product) {
      productArray.push(product);
    });
  }
  var newOrder = await {
    id: count++,
    dateofdispatch: req.body.date,
    transport: req.body.transport,
    amount: req.body.totalcost,
    product: productArray,
  };
  // do another thing and dont forget to use await

};

// somewhere in your code
createProductArray()
```